# Bldc motor speed control

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Can field orient control can be applied in BLDC motor with trapezoidal back emf?Washing machine has concentrate winding which give trapezoidal emf.  how they use FOC there?how is that working?I have also doubt in Gogoro scooter permanent magnet motor.what kind of back emf will it produce ?videos are available in YouTube.plz reply

Comment: What exactly is your question?  I see many questions and a vacuous suggestion to watch YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

BLDC motors can have various back-emf waveforms depending on magnet and stator geometry. Here are a few that I have tested (all running at part throttle on trapezoid drive):-

Kyosho DF-45 coreless ironless 2 pole inrunner 
[image]

ARC-28-47-2 4 pole slotted inrunner
[image]

Medusa 028-032-3400 6 pole slotted inrunner
[image]

Field oriented control could be applied to all of these motors, but generally works better with sine wave back-emf.

> I have also doubt in Gogoro scooter permanent magnet motor.what kind
>   of back emf will it produce?

Can't know for sure without testing it, but it appears to be a 14 pole slotted inrunner. Slotted motors often have non-sinusoidal back-emf.

[Differences between slotted and slotless motors](https://www.motioncontroltips.com/whats-the-difference-between-slotted-and-slotless-motors/)

Comment: Good answer.  Traditional FOC will try to force sinusoidal currents, so if the back EMF is trapezoidal you might get a bit more torque ripple, but it will work fine.

Comment: FOC should not have torque ripple with a trap motor if the FOC algorithm is designed for trap motors.

Comment: @m-walker95 to minimize torque ripple It doesn't just have to be 'designed for trap[ezoid] motors' but tuned to match the particular motor. This is beyond 'traditional FOC'.